# GPS positioning with Python, geopy, shapely

Tags: python, geolocation, geopy, shapely

I'm trying to work on the following scenario:

- Getting polygon coordinates from google earth
- Getting boundaries with Shapely:

  ```
  >>> polygon = Polygon([(53.349459,-6.260159),(53.349366,-6.260126),(53.349383,-6.260012),(53.349478,-6.260053),(53.349459,-6.260159)])   
  >>> polygon.bounds
  (53.349366, -6.260159, 53.349478, -6.260012)
  ```

  I am getting 2 coordinates, which are 2 border points on the top of my figure.
- Getting distance with geopy

  And now I am stuck... trying to figure out:

  1. How to find 2 other border points (in the bottom)
  2. How to detect whether a user is near (e.g. 3 meters) the polygon from any side? (left, right, up, down). in this case, I need to know not only the edges border points, but also all the border points from left, right, up and down? I can calculate the distance between the user location and the polygon, but what point to from polygon to take dynamically?
     Can I use existing libs for this, like geopy and Shapely?

  [image]

Comment: this is maybe more an question for http://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Bounds returns the bounding box of your polygon. The smallest rectangle in which the polygon fits. If you look at it it is not the coordinates of the top points.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly you have a bunch of Shapely polygons and you want to test if arbitrary points are close to these shapes. 
For this problem shapely provides [distance](http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/manual.html#object.distance):

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
polygon = Polygon([(53.349459,-6.260159),
                   (53.349366,-6.260126),
                   (53.349383,-6.260012),
                   (53.349478,-6.260053),
                   (53.349459,-6.260159)])
testpoint = Point(53.349459,-6.260190)
dist = polygon.distance(testpoint)
print(dist)
>>> 3.09999999999e-05
```

Mind you: distance is in arcs and not in meters so you have to convert them.

Comment: the distance is in arcs, if I understand correctly, only if you are using coordinates. In this case, I'm not even sure that's accurate. A better approach to measure distance of long/lat is to project the polygon first (pyproj?) and then measure it. We are using a simpler projection method that relies on the average latitude of the polygon